# Route.DeserializationResult return MAP_VERSION_MISMATCH

Tags: here-api

I Serialize the route with my android app and send to another device and use the same android app to Deserialize it, only got MAP_VERSION_MISMATCH. 
Actually the here map SDK are the same... the same app, why...

Answer (score 0):

Because the map version is different. Routes must be using the same map version for it to be serializable / deserializable.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-route-serializererror.html#topic-apiref__map-version-mismatch):
"Map version from serialized route does not match current **map** version."

Please use the MapLoader APIs to update to the latest map for both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean " MapLoader APIs" ? My understanding is that is for offline map , right ? my app is working online and the 2 tablet are running the same app, I just transferred the route data from one to the other, and the data can be deserialized correctly locally, but the other tablet failed with MAP_VERSION_MISMATCH.  and looks like the date itself is ok, otherwise maybe other error message ?

Comment: The map that your application downloads is versioned. For example, if you query the MapLoader APIs you will likely see 63.x.x.x or 65.x.x.x. That is the revision of the map currently installed for the application. You can upgrade the map to the latest version using the MapLoader APIs.

Comment: The Maps are updated as per our blog at 360.here.com. For the question you posted, it is likely one device has an older version of the map. We cannot serialize between the versions because the road geometry may have changed. (ie new roads, changed road etc etc)